# How to add a bash command output to pretty format json git log

Tags: json, bash, git

I am very new to bash and stuck with the format. I am running a bash script to loop through some commit urls(a txt file contains these and variable `repo_url` stores a url during the loop) and get the log data in json format saved to file `json.txt`.

I am able to get all the data I need in right format but I want to include repo url as well to know where a particular commit came from.

The repo url is in the form of variable `$repo_url`.

How do I include the bash command output to the pretty format json?

Here is what I have currently:

```
git log -n 1\
--pretty=format:'{"commit": "%H", "author": "%aN <%aE>", "date": "%ai", "message": """%B""", "notes": """%N""" },' \
$@  | awk 'BEGIN { print("[") } { print($0) } END { print("]") }' | python -u -c \
'import ast,json,sys; print(json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(sys.stdin.read())))'
```

But I also want to include `repo: "$repo_url"` for all the entries which is not happening right now. If I try the below code, instead of the actual url I get the string `"$repo_url"` in the output.

```
git log -n 1\
--pretty=format:'{"repo": "$repo_url", "commit": "%H", "author": "%aN <%aE>", "date": "%ai", "message": """%B""", "notes": """%N""" },' \
$@  | awk 'BEGIN { print("[") } { print($0) } END { print("]") }' | python -u -c \
'import ast,json,sys; print(json.dumps(ast.literal_eval(sys.stdin.read())))'
```

Please let me know if I should share any additional information.

Comment: Do you know [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) already?

Comment: I haven't used `jq`. Is there. a way we can include the `$repo_url` within pretty format output? Or is the only way to use `jq`? @RenaudPacalet

Comment: For what you want, I'd say it's much easier to query the Github API, which already returns JSON.

Comment: @Reino, I also need the description/message of each commit which I cannot get with the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with quotes and double-quotes to decide when the shell expansion shall occur or not. Example with `echo`:

```
$ repo_url="foo"
$ echo '"repo": "$repo_url"'
"repo": "$repo_url"
$ echo '"repo": "'"$repo_url"'"'
"repo": "foo"
```

So, in your git command:

```
git log -n1 --pretty=format:'{"repo": "'"$repo_url"'",...},' $@ | \
awk 'BEGIN { print("[") } { print($0) } END { print("]") }' | \
python ...
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. I was also wondering how this would change if we use `jq` instead? :)

Comment: `jq` is dedicated to Json parsing and processing, so it could be a replacement for your `python` script. But if you are happy with `python` you probably don't need it.

Comment: Okay. I am happy with `python` right now but I would love to explore `jq` if it makes the script cleaner/more efficient.

Comment: Hi @renaud-pacalet, the above command works well if I fetch only one commit details using `-n1` but fails with more than one, is there a solution to tackle that?

Comment: @YashikaSharma If you output several lines of log the you cannot embed the square brackets, you would have one per line. Use another way, like your initial awk command, and forget about '[%n...%n]'. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. This works fine outside the shell script but throws error if run within the shell script. Here is the gist of script that I am using https://gist.github.com/yashika51/14518677a1c8b02c5892c257dac7e3a8

Comment: Time to learn a bit more of your shell and also how to debug a script. Do not hesitate to ask **specific** questions on SO, with [MCVEs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), if there are things you do not understand. But first try to solve your issues yourself. It is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1):

> *@Reino, I also need the description/message of each commit which I cannot get with the API.*

You *can* actually. The JSON parser [xidel](/questions/tagged/xidel) is, in my opinion, the ideal command-line tool for this task. I don't know which repositories you'd like to process, so I'll use the [API url](https://api.github.com/repos/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commits) that lists the commits from the [FFmpeg repo](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git). It returns an array where each item looks like this:

```
$ xidel -s https://api.github.com/repos/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commits -e '
  $json()[sha="74e43824421bac9fa0816dce8b069eeab6f4cd07"]
'
{
  "sha": "74e43824421bac9fa0816dce8b069eeab6f4cd07",
  "node_id": "MDY6Q29tbWl0MTYxNDQxMDo3NGU0MzgyNDQyMWJhYzlmYTA4MTZkY2U4YjA2OWVlYWI2ZjRjZDA3",
  "commit": {
    "author": {
      "name": "Pierre-Anthony Lemieux",
      "email": "pal@sandflow.com",
      "date": "2021-07-18T18:07:43Z"
    },
    "committer": {
      "name": "Marton Balint",
      "email": "cus@passwd.hu",
      "date": "2021-07-29T20:38:02Z"
    },
    "message": "avformat/mxfdec: fix frame wrapping detection for J2K essence container\n\nFor JPEG 2000 essence, the MXF input format module currently uses the value of\nbyte 14 of the essence container UL to determine whether the J2K essence is\nclip- (byte 14 is 0x02) or frame-wrapped (byte 14 is 0x01). Otherwise it\nassumes an unknown wrapping.\n\nAdditional wrappings are documented in SMPTE ST422:2019:\n\n0x03: Interlaced Frame, 1 field/KLV\n0x04: Interlaced Frame, 2 fields/KLV\n0x05: Field-wrapped Picture Element\n0x06: Frame-wrapped Picture Element\n\nAnd these should also be handled as frame wrapped content.\n\nSigned-off-by: Pierre-Anthony Lemieux <pal@sandflow.com>\nSigned-off-by: Marton Balint <cus@passwd.hu>",
    [...]
  },
  [...]
}
```

To process the latest 3 commits you could do:

```
$ xidel -s https://api.github.com/repos/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commits -e '
  array{
    $json()[position() = 1 to 3]/{
      "repo":"https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git",
      "commit":sha,
      "author":commit/author/x"{name} <{email}>",
      "date":commit/author/date,
      "message":tokenize(commit/message,"\n\n")[1],
      "notes":extract(commit/message,"\n\n(.+)",1,"s")[.]
    }
  }
'
[
  {
    "repo": "https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git",
    "commit": "b9176dbfb7c209f2adf1f420df74b91df56c1fb3",
    "author": "Gyan Doshi <ffmpeg@gyani.pro>",
    "date": "2021-07-30T11:38:53Z",
    "message": "avcodec/noise_bsf: restore dropamount for backwards compatibility",
    "notes": null
  },
  {
    "repo": "https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git",
    "commit": "ae94868a576c901f313c619950ec7d8a5f6ca615",
    "author": "Paul B Mahol <onemda@gmail.com>",
    "date": "2021-07-30T07:24:49Z",
    "message": "avfilter/avf_showfreqs: switch to TX FFT from avutil",
    "notes": null
  },
  {
    "repo": "https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git",
    "commit": "74e43824421bac9fa0816dce8b069eeab6f4cd07",
    "author": "Pierre-Anthony Lemieux <pal@sandflow.com>",
    "date": "2021-07-18T18:07:43Z",
    "message": "avformat/mxfdec: fix frame wrapping detection for J2K essence container",
    "notes": "For JPEG 2000 essence, the MXF input format module currently uses the value of\nbyte 14 of the essence container UL to determine whether the J2K essence is\nclip- (byte 14 is 0x02) or frame-wrapped (byte 14 is 0x01). Otherwise it\nassumes an unknown wrapping.\n\nAdditional wrappings are documented in SMPTE ST422:2019:\n\n0x03: Interlaced Frame, 1 field/KLV\n0x04: Interlaced Frame, 2 fields/KLV\n0x05: Field-wrapped Picture Element\n0x06: Frame-wrapped Picture Element\n\nAnd these should also be handled as frame wrapped content.\n\nSigned-off-by: Pierre-Anthony Lemieux <pal@sandflow.com>\nSigned-off-by: Marton Balint <cus@passwd.hu>"
  }
]
```

---

To process the latest commit of a repo where the repo-url comes from a text-file:

```
$ xidel -s urls.txt -e '$raw'
#or
$ xidel -se 'file:read-text("urls.txt")'
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl.git
https://github.com/benibela/xidel.git

$ xidel -se '
  for $url in file:read-text-lines("urls.txt") return
  replace($url,".+/(.+/.+)\.git","https://api.github.com/repos/$1/commits")
'
https://api.github.com/repos/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commits
https://api.github.com/repos/rg3/youtube-dl/commits
https://api.github.com/repos/benibela/xidel/commits

$ xidel -se '
  array{
    for $url in file:read-text-lines("urls.txt") return
    json-doc(
      replace($url,".+/(.+/.+)\.git","https://api.github.com/repos/$1/commits")
    )(1)/{
      "repo":$url,
      "commit":sha,
      "author":commit/author/x"{name} <{email}>",
      "date":commit/author/date,
      "message":tokenize(commit/message,"\n\n")[1],
      "notes":extract(commit/message,"\n\n(.+)",1,"s")[.]
    }
  }
'
[
  {
    "repo": "https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg.git",
    "commit": "b9176dbfb7c209f2adf1f420df74b91df56c1fb3",
    "author": "Gyan Doshi <ffmpeg@gyani.pro>",
    "date": "2021-07-30T11:38:53Z",
    "message": "avcodec/noise_bsf: restore dropamount for backwards compatibility",
    "notes": null
  },
  {
    "repo": "https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl.git",
    "commit": "a8035827177d6b59aca03bd717acb6a9bdd75ada",
    "author": "bopol <bopol@e.email>",
    "date": "2021-07-01T06:53:22Z",
    "message": "[peertube] only call description endpoint if necessary (#29383)",
    "notes": null
  },
  {
    "repo": "https://github.com/benibela/xidel.git",
    "commit": "6d3b34408a0b0f0ed691753ea37860e98bcc29e6",
    "author": "benibela <benito@benibela.de>",
    "date": "2021-07-20T14:57:15Z",
    "message": "perhaps remove recursive follow",
    "notes": null
  }
]
```

Comment: This looks very interesting. Thank you @Reino for the answer. I'll try this out.